# converting unixtimestamp to datetime failed to yield correct result in impala/hive

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp

Apologize if this has been answered sometime and somewhere else.
My query:

```
select from_unixtime(1501083119,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

This returns correct result:

> 2017-07-26 15:31:59

My data is like:
1501081198789

as you can see, the value is quite different than the one in the test query, if I put this to the query:
it returns NULL

Seems the last four digits are causing the problem, how do I get this working?

Thanks lots.

Comment: Divide by 1000 to transform that "number of miliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" into a "number of seconds". Pas d'autre choix !

Comment: Thanks. you mean the last four digits 8789 means something between 2017-07-26 15:31:59 and 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your epoch time is in milli seconds, if you modify your query as below you will get your desired output:

```
select from_unixtime(cast('1501081198789'/1000 as bigint),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

> 2017-07-26 10:59:58

Comment: Thank you, can you elaborate the last four digit in the original Unix timestamp "8789"?, can I get something like: 2015-11-01 21:10:00.123456789?

Comment: If you are purely looking for the milliseconds to display too, all you need to do is

`select cast(1501081198789 as timestamp)`

Comment: Thanks, returns NULL in impala